# Combining map and padded_batch in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

To increase the performance on input pipeline tensorflow documentation recommends using `tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch` instead of separate `.map` and `.batch` functions ([Data input pipeline performance](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets)). But how to combine `.map` and `.padded_batch` functions in input pipeline?